# Facebook post impressions are null in FQL stream query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

According to the [FQL Stream documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) the following query is supposed to return impression counts when run by an authenticated page owner, yet it never does. We have the page owner authenticating directly in the [graph api explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with extended permissions (read_stream, read_insights), but the impression counts are always null.

Is *anyone* able to get this working?

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, impressions FROM stream WHERE actor_id = {owned_page} and source_id = {owned_page}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you come up with anything?

Comment: Doesn't work here either.

Answer (score 4):

I think its missing in the documentation, but you should make this call using the **page access token** instead of user access token to get it worked.

So here are the steps:

1. Get the following permissions from the user and get the `user access_token`:

   - `manage_pages` - to get the page access token
   - `read_insights` - to read the impressions (as mentioned in the doc)
   - `read_stream` - for all posts that the current session user is able to view
2. Using that token, get the `page access_token` with the call-

   `/{page-id}?fields=access_token`
3. (*optional*) Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322405/1343690) to extend this page access token that will **never** expire. (Basically to avoid some steps)
4. Using the page access token, run your query-

   `SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, impressions FROM stream WHERE actor_id = {owned_page} and source_id = {owned_page}`

   This will fetch you the impressions(if any) in the result.

   [image]

Hope that helps.!

Comment: I'm having some problems doing this here. I have a very simple page (100 likes) and cannot get post impressions no matter what I try. Is is supposed to work with any post or only promoter ones?