# Is "Reach" of a particular Facebook post "public"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I've been searching through docs but can't find a definite clear answer.

The Likes,comments and shares of a particular Facebook post are public i.e. If i query via fql  the summary(insights) of a public facebook post from any random public facebook page,it would return the likes,comments,shares of that FB post.

I 've been trying to know "Reach" of a particular post of a random public facebook page,but in vain. Is it known only to Facebook page admin/owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `impressions` of a post with the following query-

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, impressions FROM stream WHERE actor_id = {owned_page} and source_id = {owned_page}
```

But yes, you need some permissions- `manage_pages`, `read_insights`, `read_stream` etc. to fetch the impressions.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451815/facebook-post-impressions-are-null-in-fql-stream-query/22952299#22952299) I've explained the same in detail.

Comment: manage_pages,etc permissions of the respective owner of the page right?

Comment: Yes, else how will you get the access token for that page

Comment: In short, insights of a public post is NOT public right?, coz only the  admin can see them with manage_page permission